# Taylor formula and $\sin(x) - x$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to prove the existence of a limit and am stuck in a step that involves applying the Taylor formula to the sine function.

In short, we arrive at 
$$
\frac{\sin(x) - x}{ x}.\tag{1}
$$

But then we apply the Taylor formula to this at $x = 0$ to get 
$$
\sin(x) = x + \frac{1}{2}(-\sin(\xi))x^2,
$$ 
where $\xi$ is between $0$ and $x$. This means that one can re-write (1) as 
$$
\frac{-\sin(\xi)x^2}{2x}.
$$

I don't understand how the Taylor formula has been applied here. Would somebody be able to help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you have the correct Taylor formula for $\sin(x)$. You should **not** have a $\sin(\sigma)$ present.

Comment: Sorry. Actually it is a $\xi$, I just chose the character arbitrarily. It doesn't seem like this is a Taylor expansion nor approximation, I was wondering if this kind of manipulation was familiar to anyone.

Comment: Are you trying to find the limit of 
$$
\frac{\sin(x) - x}{ x}.\tag{1}
$$  as $x\to 0?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is used is [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder):

> Let $f : {\bf R}\to{\bf R}$ be $k+1$ times differentiable on the open interval with $f^{(k)}$ continuous on the closed interval between $a$ and $x$. Then
>   $$
> f(x)=p_k(x)+R_k(x)
> $$
>   where
>   $$
> {p_{k}(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+{\frac {f''(a)}{2!}}(x-a)^{2}+\cdots +{\frac {f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}}(x-a)^{k}} 
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> {R_{k}(x)={\frac {f^{(k+1)}(\xi_{L})}{(k+1)!}}(x-a)^{k+1}}$$ 
>   for some real number $\xi_L$ between $a$ and $x$.

In your case:
$$
f(x)=\sin x, \quad a=0,\quad  k=1.
$$

Comment: Thank you. That is clearly explained.

Answer (score 0):

Taylor's formula for $\sin$ is
$$ \sin x = x - \frac16x^3 + \frac1{120}x^5 - \frac1{5040}x^7 + \cdots $$
and therefore,
$$ \sin x -x = - \frac16x^3 + \frac1{120}x^5 - \frac1{5040}x^7 + \cdots. $$
There shouldn't be a $\sin\sigma$ term in the taylor expansion. The coefficients of the taylor series of any smooth function is given by $\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$, which is clearly a constant.

Comment: Thank you YiFan. I mixed up Taylor's theorem and the expansion in my question.

Comment: No problem. I suppose Taylor has too many results named after him :)

Answer (score 0):

Taylor's Theorem is a powerfultheorem that works for functions of an arbitrary number of derivatives. It states that if $f$ is $n$ times continuously differentiable on an open interval containing $a$, then for some $\sigma\in(a,x)$, (or $\sigma\in(x,a))$

$$f(x)=f(a)+(x-a)f'(a)+\frac{(x-a)^2}{2}f''(x)+...+\frac{(x-a)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f^{(n-1)}(x)+\frac{(x-a)^{n}}{n!}f^{(n)}(\sigma)$$

The theorem is not actually difficult to show; it requires repeated use of integration by parts as well as a generalization of the mean value theorem for integrals.

For your case, we take $n=2$ and $a=0$ to get

$$f(x)=f(0)+xf'(x)+\frac{x^2}{2}f''(\sigma)$$

Letting $f(x)=\sin(x)$, we have

$$\sin(x)=\sin(0)+x\cos(0)+\frac{x^2}{2}(-\sin(\sigma))=x-\frac{x^2}{2}\sin(\sigma)$$

This is how they get

$$\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x}=-\frac{x}{2}\sin(\sigma)$$

This only down side is that we don't know what $\sigma$ is, but we know it exists between $0$ and $x$. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Josh. That was very helpful.